# Extract value when a word is found in the file in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

My text file is below listed. I want to find the following values:

- after `State:`, the value of `Texas` and `NJ`
- after `MVR Type`, the value of `Renewal` and `New`
- after `License:`, the value of `23393` and `2423433`
- after `Company Name`, the value of `ABC INC` and `ABC INC CORP`
- after `Department`, the value of `NSTD` and `NSTD`

> Driver Personal Information
>
> State:    Texas   MVR Type    Renewal
>
> License:  23393   Company Name    ABC INC
>
> Department    NSTD
>
> State:    NJ  MVR Type    New
>
> License:  2423433 Company Name    ABC INC CORP
>
> Department    NSTD

The code from which I am getting the index is:

```
import re
word='State'
state=re.search(r'\b({})\b'.format(word), string)
print(state.start())
print(state.end())
```

This gives me correct index but I am not able to search for with word=`State:` with this regex.

if I use `state=re.search(r"State:\s(.*)", string)` it gives me `state.group(1)` value as `Texas    MVR Type    Renewal`

I only want `Texas` in its value.

Comment: `State:\s*(?<state>.+)\s*MVR Type\s*(?<mvrType>.+)|License:\s*(?<license>.+)\s*Company Name (?<company>.+)|Department\s*(?<dept>.+)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that you are forgetting that `.*` is going to match as much as it possibly can, including spaces. If you are sure that there will only be letters, you could change your search to:

```
r"State:\s+([a-zA-Z]*)"
```

In regex, the `[]` groups state a list of characters that can be included, so anything else will not match. Here's the same thing if you wanted it to be delimited by spaces:

```
r"State:\s+([^ ]*)"
```

But some states have spaces. If you know what comes next, and "MVR Type" will always be next, you can include that:

```
r"State:(.*)\s+MVR Type"
```

If you wanted to go a little further, I would recommend using regular expression named groups, which Python supports, especially since you'll want to grab multiple values on a single line.

Here's some information on named groups: https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Here's some example code:

```
text = """Driver Personal Information
State: Texas MVR Type Renewal
License: 23393 Company Name ABC INC
Department NSTD"""

information_rx = re.compile(
    r'State:\s*(?P<state>.*)\s+MVR Type\s*(?P<mvr_type>[a-zA-Z]+).*'
    r'License:\s*(?P<license>[0-9]+)\s+Company Name\s+(?P<company>.+)$.*'
    r'Department\s+(?P<department>.+)',
    re.M|re.S
)

information_match = information_rx.search(text)
if information_match:
    print "State: {}".format(information_match.group('state'))
    print "MVR Type: {}".format(information_match.group('mvr_type'))
    print "License: {}".format(information_match.group('license'))
    ....
```

This allows you to capture all of the information in one pass, and also gives you much control over exactly what information is captured.

Comment: Thanks man. I am new at reg ex and was reading the python doc for it but what you provided is really helpful!

Comment: I'm very glad! Feel free to upvote or mark as answered if it works. Python handles regex, somewhat, but I feel like it's not always the best tool for learning it. If you have access to Linux/Unix(/Mac?), you could try using `grep` on the command line with `--color` and `-E`. Starting off, this may be a good tool: https://regexone.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
text = """Driver Personal Information
State: Texas MVR Type Renewal
License: 23393 Company Name ABC INC
Department NSTD"""
```

First, we need to replace the occurrences of `\n` with `' '`.

Then we need to `split` on all the spaces (this is the default) to separate each piece of data.

Then just find the indexes of the key words and take one more than that to get each value.

In code, the steps outlined above would look something like:

```
words = text.replace("\n", " ").split()
state = words[words.index("State:")+1]
type = words[words.index("Type")+1]
license = words[words.index("License:")+1]
company_name = words[words.index("Name")+1] + " " + words[words.index("Name")+2]
department = words[words.index("Department")+1]
```

which gives results of:

```
>>> state
'Texas'
>>> type
'Renewal'
>>> license
'23393'
>>> company_name
'ABC INC'
>>> department
'NSTD'
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.This is helpful but if my company name is 'ABC INC CORP' then it will give me the CORP word. They can long with multiple spaces. Also the text is repetitive with these  text = """Driver Personal Information
State: Texas MVR Type Renewal
License: 23393 Company Name ABC INC
Department NSTD                                  Driver Personal Information
State: New Jersey MVR Type Renewal
License: 23393 Company Name ABC INC CORP
Department ABCD""""""

Comment: @RohitMankotia Ok then this solution won't work... You should have really been more specific in the question though.

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited my question now.